# iOS Parse HTML (article)

Tags: html, ios

I need to parse HTML code in between tags `<div id="id">SomeHtml</div>`. 
Then i need to change attributes in the img and iframe tags and return a String with modified HTML code to put it into the webView.

Which objective-с library can I use and what method returns the modified string. 
And maybe there is an example of code with similar goals?

Comment: Maaybe, this helps: https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

Comment: I think link is useful: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Hpple`, for obtaining the code between tags SomeHtml", then added css, that would adjust the `<iframe>` and `<img>`.

Comment: can you write some examples for adding css or attribute for `<img>`?